# Visual Studio 2012 1 of 4 projects not loading

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

- Visual Studio 2012, TFS, Windows 7

We have a C# solution that has 4 projects. One of the projects fails to load. When loading the solution I recieve and error stating "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details." The output window shows "$devpath\Remits\Business\Admin.Portal\Remits\Business\Admin.Portal\Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj" where $devpath stands in for local src path for brevity.

If I attempt to reload the project I get an error stating "The project file '$devpath\Remits\Business\Admin.Portal\Remits\Business\Admin.Portal\Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj' has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer."

The path to the project is $devpath\Remits\Business\Admin.Portal\Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj. You will notice that there is a section in the path that is being repeated unnecessarily. I have used notepad++ to look at the .sln and .csproj but I don't know enough about the fields to have fixed the issue.

I have look for possible solutions but haven't found a fix yet. Some of the sites I have looked at suggest deleting the .suo file but that didn't resolve the problem. If it is needed to see some of the fields in the .sln and .csproj I will be happy to provide them. Thanks for any help you can provide.

http://tzuhsun.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/the-project-file-0-has-been-moved-renamed-or-is-not-on-your-computer/

http://codingcramp.blogspot.com/2011/03/project-file-has-been-moved-renamed-or.html

older:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/tfsgeneral/thread/a4c3f944-f36b-4a8d-9cb5-a1133f717ce5

Solution file info:

```
    Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Remits.Business.Admin.Portal", "Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj", "{2D08EC70-FAC0-4360-910C-0435FD4BE6E6}"
    Global
        GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
            SccNumberOfProjects = 4
            SccProjectUniqueName0 = Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj
            SccProjectName0 = .
            SccAuxPath0 = http://someTFSserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
            SccLocalPath0 = .
            SccProvider0 = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
                   ..snip..
        GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
            SccNumberOfProjects = 4
            SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
            SccTeamFoundationServer = http://someTFSserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection       
            SccProjectUniqueName0 = Remits.Business.Admin.Portal.csproj
            SccProjectName0 = Remits/Business/Admin.Portal
            SccLocalPath0 = Admin.Portal
```

Comment: From the solution file: "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00". Also this project file is in the same directory as the solution file.

Comment: can you post your solution file content? just the part that's related to the project.

Comment: added references of the project from the solution file. i noticed that the GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) appears twice. But I don't think this has anything to do with it.

Comment: The solution file says that the format version is 11.00 but a comment says # Visual Studio 2010. This indicates to me that this is up converted from a VS2010 solution. I have opened the solution in VS2010 and I am able to build the solution.

Comment: for vs 2010 solution file, the first two line should be "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00" and "# Visual Studio 2010". for vs 2012 solution file, it should be "Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00" and "# Visual Studio 2012". also, i have never seen two "GlobalSection" comes with two "TeamFoundationVersionControl".

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Version_history) says that internal version for VS2012 is 11. I thought the internal version related to the format version but other sites confirm that they are not related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not familiar with the solution file structure, I suggest you:

1. make an extra copy of the unloading project
2. remove the unloading project form your solution and make sure it's gone from the file system except the extra copy you made
3. add a new project to recreate the unloading project to your solution
4. once your solution loads fine, you can remove your extra backup

Comment: This project is large and somewhat complex. I would like to avoid reconstructing it if I can, but if it is not a matter of editing the solution or project file I guess I will have to.

Comment: You can fix the problem by editing the solution or project file, but from my experience, it usually not worth the time and very risky. When you reconstruct the project, you only need to copy the files over and add them as "existing items". so there's little risk comparing to editing the solution or project files manually. Maybe the first thing you should try is to remove it from solution and then add it back as "existing project". That'll tell you if it's the solution file's problem. Otherwise, it's the project file.

Comment: I have tried to remove the project and add it back as an existing project but that didn't work.

Comment: I am able to build  the project using vs2010 but I have decided to reconstruct the project to fix this problem in vs2012.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with a web project and it turned out to be related to corrupt IIS Express configuration.

I manually removed the project bindings in the IIS Express config and tool out the line;

in my .csproj file. Hope this helps somebody else who finds their way here.

Comment: Corrupt IIS express was my issue as well, when trying to set up remote debugging

Answer (score 0):

The same problems had occurred with me! 
No need to do those above things!
Check:
If you have changed any folder name or folder structure while saving last time.
Check whether all files are at their correct place and correctly named?

That's it! You will get your solution ready, cause i get it!